# VBA/Rule to change subject line of incoming email then move to folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to write a script that will take specific incoming emails, change their subject line, then move that email to a specific folder.

I can find scripts that will change the subject line while the message itself is open, but when tied to a "Move to folder" rule, the subject does not change.

I've tried this code which adds text the subject line of a message which I have open.

```
Sub myRuleMacro(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Sub AddToEndOfSubjectLine()
If ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Save
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.subject = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.subject & " HELLO!"
End Sub

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I've also tried another code which changes any messages I have highlighted within a folder, I can't get it to paste properly into the post.

Comment: Sorry BigBen, not trying to be difficult. I'm new to Outlook's VBA. I'm decently dangerous with Excel's. I've tried several different code strings in Outlook to accomplish this, but haven't had any luck. Just trying to find an efficient way to add some text to a subject line for a series of automated emails that come in poorly named.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is an example, try it*

```
Public Sub Example(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Print on Immediate Window

    Item.Subject = Item.Subject & " HELLO!"
        Item.Save

End Sub
```

*To test the script, try selecting the Email and run the following code*

```
Private Sub TestMsg()
    Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Example olMsg

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello,
I tried the script, replacing folder name with my destination folder 
    .Folders("Rpt Daily Exceptions")

When attached to a rule, outlook acts like it wants to move the email by having a status window pop up quickly; but the message does not move, nor does the subject get amended.

When attached to a rule where the rule moves the message, it does move, of course, but still the subject does not change at all.

Comment: Through the Rules & Alerts screen. I tried "with specific words in the subject" then "Run script" and chose the script you laid out. I also tried: "with specific words in the subject" then "move to folder" then "run script".

Comment: The script does return an error, operation failed an object could not be found. It then references the set subfolder section of your script

Comment: it is line number 3

Comment: I just verified, and the two are typed exactly the same down to the case matching. My folder in outlook is named `Rpt Daily Exceptions` and I have it referenced in the script as `.Folders("Rpt Daily Exceptions")`

Comment: @safedave is your subfolder under inbox?

Comment: It is not a subfolder of my inbox. It is a subfolder of my mail box. Just to be clear: it is a sub of "myemailaddress@email.com" on the navigation pane. It is not nested under the inbox folder.

Comment: okay @safedave I'm not sure about your subfolder- so use the rule to move email to folder- see updated script

Answer (score 0):

Item is the incoming mail.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration

Sub myRuleMacro(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

' Rules Wizard is misleading
' The move has to be in the code, not in the rules

Dim inboxFolder As folder
Dim mailboxFolder As folder
Dim destFolder As folder
Dim destFolderStr As String

Item.Subject = Item.Subject & " HELLO!"
Debug.Print Item.Subject

' One way to reference a folder
'  is to walk the folder tree from a known folder
Set inboxFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set mailboxFolder = inboxFolder.Parent
Debug.Print "Mailbox associated with the default inbox: " & mailboxFolder

destFolderStr = "name of folder at same level as inbox"
Set destFolder = mailboxFolder.folders(destFolderStr)

Item.Move destFolder

End Sub
```

You may test with an open mailitem.

```vb
Private Sub simulateIncomingMail_BeforeTrueTest()
    myRuleMacro ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Sub
```